Can't colcon build ros2 humble package for UR10e control
I am using ros2 humble to control a ur10e robot. I have successfully installed drivers and can use ros2 action send_goal /scaled_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory control_msgs/action/FollowJointTrajectory ... in the terminal to verify that the controller is active and working. When I try to run a cpp file that is meant to achieve the same goal however I get an error when I try to build the package using colcon build. The error message is quite long but part of it is this:
> In member function ‘void ArmMove::send_goal()’:
/home/usr/some_dir/src/my_controller/src/arm_move.cpp:88:48: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘rclcpp_action::Client<control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory>::GoalResponseCallback’ {aka ‘std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory> >)>’} and ‘ArmMove::send_goal()::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory> > >)>’)
   88 |     send_goal_options.goal_response_callback = goal_response_callback;
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/future:47,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /home/usr/some_dir/src/my_controller/src/arm_move.cpp:1:

I am not sure what could be the problem but it seems that rclcpp_action cannot be called the way it is in my cpp file:
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "rclcpp_action/rclcpp_action.hpp"
#include "control_msgs/action/follow_joint_trajectory.hpp"
#include "trajectory_msgs/msg/joint_trajectory.hpp"
#include "trajectory_msgs/msg/joint_trajectory_point.hpp"

class ArmMove : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  using FollowJointTrajectory = control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory;
  using GoalHandleFollowJointTrajectory = rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<FollowJointTrajectory>;

  explicit ArmMove(const rclcpp::NodeOptions & options = rclcpp::NodeOptions())
  : Node("arm_move", options)
  {
    this->action_client_ = rclcpp_action::create_client<FollowJointTrajectory>(
      this, "/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory");

    this->send_goal();
  }

private:
  rclcpp_action::Client<FollowJointTrajectory>::SharedPtr action_client_;

  void send_goal()
  {
    if (!this->action_client_->wait_for_action_server(std::chrono::seconds(10))) {
      RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Action server not available after waiting");
      return;
    }

    auto goal_msg = FollowJointTrajectory::Goal();
    goal_msg.trajectory.header.stamp = this->now();
    goal_msg.trajectory.joint_names = {
      "shoulder_pan_joint",
      "shoulder_lift_joint",
      "elbow_joint",
      "wrist_1_joint",
      "wrist_2_joint",
      "wrist_3_joint"
    };

    trajectory_msgs::msg::JointTrajectoryPoint point;
    point.positions = {0.785, -1.57, 0.785, 0.785, 0.785, 0.785};
    point.time_from_start = rclcpp::Duration::from_seconds(5);

    goal_msg.trajectory.points.push_back(point);

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Sending goal");

    auto send_goal_options = rclcpp_action::Client<FollowJointTrajectory>::SendGoalOptions();
    send_goal_options.goal_response_callback =
      [this](std::shared_future<GoalHandleFollowJointTrajectory::SharedPtr> future) {
        auto goal_handle = future.get();
        if (!goal_handle) {
          RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Goal was rejected by server");
        } else {
          RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Goal accepted by server, waiting for result");
        }
      };
    send_goal_options.result_callback =
      [this](const GoalHandleFollowJointTrajectory::WrappedResult & result) {
        switch (result.code) {
          case rclcpp_action::ResultCode::SUCCEEDED:
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Goal succeeded");
            break;
          case rclcpp_action::ResultCode::ABORTED:
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Goal was aborted");
            return;
          case rclcpp_action::ResultCode::CANCELED:
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Goal was canceled");
            return;
          default:
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Unknown result code");
            return;
        }
      };
    send_goal_options.feedback_callback =
      [this](GoalHandleFollowJointTrajectory::SharedPtr,
             const std::shared_ptr<const FollowJointTrajectory::Feedback> feedback) {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Feedback: time from start: %d.%09d",
                    feedback->actual.time_from_start.sec,
                    feedback->actual.time_from_start.nanosec);
      };

    this->action_client_->async_send_goal(goal_msg, send_goal_options);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto node = std::make_shared<ArmMove>();
  rclcpp::spin(node);
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

Does anyone know how to setup the callback function properly? I am not even quite sure what the exact issue is. Thank you very much!

Looks to me like a type mismatch:
The goal_response_callback expects a GoalResponseCallback type, which is defined as std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory>>)>.
The lambda function provided does not match this expected type, where I believe the lambda type is:
std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory>>>, which includes a std::shared_future.

That was exactly right!!! Thank you so much for your fast help, it helped tremendously.

Please make sure to click "accept" (left hand side of the answer) on my answer to mark it as closed :).
